# Linking to CSS file in Django HTML template

Tags: html, css, django

I am building a simple Django app, and my CSS is not showing up on the development server, even though it does work if I simply open the HTML file that links to it in my browser. I've investigated other related questions on SO, as well as the official tutorial on serving static files, but still can't figure out how to make my CSS work.

I'm a novice, so please advise in simplest terms possible (but not simpler).

Thanks!

directory structure:

```
uber
  uber
  static
    css
      style.css
  templates
    home.html
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/pavelfage/Desktop/Hacking/django/uber/static/'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = ''

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    #'/Users/pavelfage/Desktop/Hacking/django/uber/uberpoll/static',
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '(au)ipe++*c6e6r1s00z9d99qgsx!loqh*-!hcqys=6&amp;bjk#*a'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'uber.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'uber.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/Users/pavelfage/Desktop/Hacking/django/uber/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'uberpoll'
)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from uber import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'uberpoll.views.home'),
    # url(r'^uber/', include('uber.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
)
```

HTML head with link:

```
<head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dev server only automatically serves files through the staticfiles framework only.

You should really just add your media folder to your `STATICFILES_DIRS` to take advantage of the framework.

But, if you want to serve `MEDIA_ROOT` at `MEDIA_URL` in development, you'll have to set up a URLConf that serves these yourself.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#staticfiles-other-directories

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

Comment: Ok - I added the absolute path to my static folder (which contains the CSS, but not the HTML file) into STATICFILES_DIRS. And I commented out the URLConf in urls.py (the one you outlined). It's still not working - do you know what I might be missing?